# Need to Hide and show Image in ListView (Image is an item in the custom list)

Tags: android, listview

I have to show an image on the clicked item in Listview.
I have used a custom Listview and trying to hide all the images initially and show image on selected item only and hide the image in other item position.

```
listData.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.settings_system_details_dashboard_view)));

    listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectionPosition = position;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    adapter = new SettingsListAdapter(this, listData, selectionPosition);
    listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the above code is my main activity

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings_custom_list, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_activity_settings_custom_list);
    ImageView selection = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.iv_activity_settings_custom_list);

    title.setText(mItems.get(position));
    if(selectionPos == position)
        selection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        selection.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return vi;
}
```

this is in the adapter

but the `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not helping as the `selectionPosition (updated position)` is not passing to the adapter!

Let me know how to send the position to the adapter from activity to show and hide image in the adapter!

Comment: `selectionPosition = position;` will only update the value in the Activity, not the adapter since it is not a reference to an Integer object

Answer (score 0):

You can have a setter method in your adapter to set the selected position and based on that position you can do whatever you want.

```
private int selectionPos;

    public void setSelectedPos(int selectedPos){
      this.selectionPos = selectedPos;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Make your ImageView Visible on click of every position ?
If yes then you will have to use POJO/Model class.
Take a Boolean Value in the model class and set it to true on the click of Listview position.
And check the Boolean value in your adapter.

And in the OnItemClickListener() just call  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```